# Can't figure out why my app is requesting root...?

Tags: java, android, root

I ask for the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

But the root request doesn't happen until I enter one of my activities.  Could it be that this activity has `android:noHistory = true`?   I can provide the code for the entire activity if needed (it's about 500 lines, and my Java is not so great so I wouldn't be too psyched to read it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:noHistory` doesn't require root access.  To help figure out where the request for root is made, place a breakpoint in your activity and step through until you hit the request.

Comment: @hatboysam Try debugging on the same device that you are getting the root request on rather than an emulator.